# Converting WGS84 to ETRS89 in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84

I have a data which has no projection and has WGS84 as a coordinate System. I need to Import this data and Analyse it other data which have ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N as a projection System.

I have tried to give the first data the same projection System through "Define Projection" but it goes to a wrong place.

What other possibility is there to fit these data?

Answer (score 1):

Use Project Tool.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/project.htm

Define projection is for feature classes without any CRS defined.

Also check:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.X\Documentation

for

> geographic_transformations.pdf

which will help you to pick correct transformation.

Comment: I try to do excatly as you siad but the result is it correct. I used the Information for the "ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N " but it has a big shift to another location

Comment: Does your other data have eastings in the 32.5 million range? Try using 4647 instead.